# Should I avoid Friday interviews?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry

Is avoiding Friday interviews generally a good practice, especially for technical rounds in the software industry?

Context:
I had a rather rough interview on Friday that shook my confidence.

It opened up with the interviewer saying he needs more than 30 minutes (our booked time) for this type of interview, and that he had a hard stop right at the ending of our time.

It turned into a fast paced set of rather trivia oriented questions.
For a few I was stumped (think code golf), for another I had a technically correct answer but different than his desired answer, and interviewer was rather dismissive and I was not given time to detail why I chose my solution and its trade offs.

In hindsight I suspect the issue was that this interview was the end of the interviewers work week, and he had little interest in doing an interview so was rather hostile.

Is avoiding Friday interviews generally a good practice, especially for technical rounds in the software industry?

Comment: I will note that I confirmed my proposed solution would work by talking through this with a peer. (And that peer confirmed that 'under the hood' my solution was actually doing exactly what he suggested.) Cannot say specifics given NDA.

Comment: The code golf bit I am trying to treat as having a silver lining - I am studying some of those specific concepts which I had not used before. (I am in more of a devOps space than SWE, so getting great depth there is sometimes a good signal.)

Comment: I'm always really upbeat and positive when it's Friday, so I'm not sure what types of inferences you can make...

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to extrapolate an entire pattern from a single data point. It sounds like this particular interviewer just... sucks.

Comment: I am trying to make the feedback/signal I get actionable - best I can figure is I should study subject X which stumped me, and maybe avoid Friday afternoon rounds.

Comment: @Panky That's a pretty stupid mindset. Not every feedback/signal needs to be acted upon, especially if it's basically noise. You're better of spending your time studying.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Yeah I might be taking this signal too seriously - mostly started this question thread to crowd source if avoiding Friday is wise or not. n=2 currently but signs are pointing to 'don't worry about it' :)

Comment: The singular of data is not anecdote. One or two data points will.not predict a trend.

Comment: It sounds like the interviewer was having a bad day/week/month and wasn’t particularly vested in the interview or its outcome…or he’s just a jerk. I’ve had interviews like this on various weekdays. Probably not a temporal phenomenon.

Comment: I had most interviews on Mondays and Fridays simply because it allows for weekend travel and an extra day to check out the place and the surroundings without having to take more time off from your current job.

Comment: And what evidence did you have for thinking that Friday had anything to do with it? It sounds like you're grasping at straws.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two ways to answer this question - the first is from a Statistical perspective - in which case the answer is 'No' - because Statistically, it has the greatest chance to leading to employment [Source](https://www.findmyprofession.com/career-advice/best-and-worst-days-of-the-week-for-job-interviews/)

However, the broader question (without the strict appeal to Stats - and I'll note the difference between Friday and Thursday is not massive) - is that a bad interview can happen on any day and for any reason.

I'd be more inclined to mark up a single bad experience to the immediate factors (that being - the Interviewer and their style) than any external factors.

There are stats out there on things that at a population level have an impact (my favorite being Criminals who get sentenced before Lunch receive harsher sentences than those sentenced after) - but at those differences are marginal and the individual factors have a far *far* greater impact than these marginal factors.

Comment: Thanks for a more numerical answer (though I wish they cited the studies they are referring too). Marking this as accepted since it seems like good guidance.

Answer (score 8):

**No. Fridays are not a problem. You already identified the problem.**

The problem was that the interviewer did not have enough time to do the interview. It wasn't "the end of the interviewers work week, and he had little interest in doing an interview". It wasn't even the end of his week. He had a hard stop, which means he had something else important he was supposed to be doing afterwards.

My guess is that someone in HR screwed up, booked you a 30 minute interview when the interviewer wanted an hour or more. This happens all the time, and yes the interviewer was annoyed (which can come across as "hostile") but probably not with you. However this is as likely to happen on a Monday as it is on a Friday. It is rather unfair of the interviewer not to cancel the interview if he thought there wasn't enough time to do the job properly, but we don't know when he found out about it.

My advice for the future is that if this happens again, immediately say "I'd be happy to come back when there is enough time to do this properly."  Do this even if the whole mess is not your fault and it would be a huge inconvenience for you. This shows you are cooperative, a team player, understanding of other people's problems, really interested in the job - exactly the sort of person interviewers are looking to hire.

Comment: "My advice for the future is that if this happens again, immediately say "I'd be happy to come back when there is enough time to do this properly."" This seems like great advice, I will follow it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every company has at least a few managers who are awful at doing interviews, or who are having an unexpectedly bad day when you show up for the interview.

That doesn't necessarily say anything about the company as a whole, if there are other managers. Heck, it may not even indicate that this manager is bad at the rest of their job; they may just not be comfortable talking to strangers. And though this has always surprised me,  few companies have done a really good job of training interviewers; I didn't get good advice on this from IBM until after I'd been with the company for decades.

By all means review after each interview to see if there was a way you could have given better answers or asked better questions. But some things are just random luck, good or bad

Answer (score -1):

> Should I avoid Friday interviews?

No.

The issues that you experienced in your interview can happen any day of the week.  In your case you may have dodged a bullet of a bad company considering that they proceeded to interview you knowing that they had not allocated sufficient time for your interview rather than re-scheduling to give both parties the best opportunity to have a successful interview.

> In hindsight I suspect the issue was that this interview was the end of the interviewers work week, and he had little interest in doing an interview so was rather hostile.

If that's true, then this interviewer is a person who absolutely should not be interviewing potential candidates.  Once again, this is more of a sign of a bad company than a general interview pattern across all companies.

Comment: Or a sign of a bad interviewer. Or an interviewer who is having an especially bad day. Which may say nothing about the rest of the company, or even about that manager's competence in other areas.